# pairwise distances used as features for classification

Tags: svm, matlab, distance, feature-engineering

I have a feature matrix 977x3

```
features = rand(977,3);
```

where each row is an observation and each column is a feature.

I calculate the pairwise distances between point with

```
dissimilarities = pdist(features);
```

and then I scale it with

```
feature_transf = mdscale(dissimilarities,3);
```

I use the new set of features (feature_transf) for classification.

Does it have any sense? I have good classification accuracy training a SVM with 10 fold cross validation.

Can you please tell me if it is methodologically incorrect?

Thanks,
Gabriele

Comment: What was the reason to do MDS on just 3-dimensional configuration of points and, further, to request 3 dimensions from this MDS? Formally there is no mistake in that, only that it is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

The usual thing in SVM is to learn from the features directly - so you should give the `features`  array to the SVM.

But let us see what you are doing with the transformations. `dissimilarities` is a triangular or square matrix of distances. But then you are using MDS to project the data into 3 dimensions so that there is a low error between the true distances and the distances in the projection (this is what MDS does in a non-formal language). But the original data came from a 3D space - so all these transformations are doing is adding maybe a little error to the relative positions of the original data (because of the MDS transformation) and  rotating and maybe reflecting the original data. So these transformations did not change the original data in any way that matters to the SVM algorithm.

Comment: Hi Jacques, Thanks for your reply. Would a kmean be affected by this kind of transformation?

Comment: Also no. you started with 3D data, calculated the distances, and than mapped it back to 3D. The only algorithm that may care about this is decisions rules, since they are not invariant to rotations. All others are insensitive to this transformation

Comment: Thanks again. I cannot explain then an improvement of the classfication performance from 55% to 82% using dissimilarities + MDS...